# how to pass python variable in os.system or subprocess?

Tags: python, linux, shell, scripting, os.system

I have a python function that generates random string using the random library and assigns it to a variable in python I want to use that in `os.system` command as in

```
os.system("mysql -u root --password=variable here < /tmp/db.setup")
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `f-string`

```
os.system(f"mysql -u root --password={variable_name} < /tmp/db.setup")
```

Answer (score 0):

String interpolation or f-string (other answer provided concurrently with mine):

```
os.system("mysql -u root --password=$'%s' < /tmp/db.setup" % (password,))
```

I would wrap that in a function so you pass in the variable.  If your password contain any shell magic like !, ?, * etc then you need to quote it (like I did).  If your password contain ' you need to quote that with '.

Use the mysql module instead of the os.system.